# python - IO Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory when downloading package

Tags: python, file, windows-7

I was trying to download a Python wrapper called rawpy on my Windows machine. I used the command "pip install rawpy". I have already looked at many other SO threads but could find no solution. The exact error is :

> IO Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'external/LibRawcmake/CMakeLists.txt'

The only dependency for the wrapper is numpy, which I successfully installed. I would like to know how to fix this. Quite new to Python, so any information would help.

Comment: A very misleading error message I admit. Do you use Python 3.6 by any chance? I don't provide Windows/macOS packages for this version yet. If so, please use 3.5 for now, and let me know if it works, then I'll write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By separate communication the OP said that the installed pip version is 7.1.0 and Python 2.7. The solution was to update pip to a version >= 8. The underlying issue is related to [SOABI tag handling](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3800) in Python 2, particularly when creating the binary wheels with pip >= 8 and trying to load them in pip < 8. pip 7 didn't identify the available binary wheels as compatible and instead downloaded the source distribution which then failed to install spectacularly.

Answer (score 0):

User letmaik was able to help me with this. It turned out that the error was caused by my version of pip being too old. The command "python -m pip install -U pip" did not work to upgrade pip; "easy_install -U pip" was required. This allowed rawpy to be installed successfully.